# Structure over flexible array member

Tags: c, c99, strict-aliasing

I'm writing a C program (g++ compilable) that has to deal with a lot of different structures, all coming from a buffer with a predefined format. The format specifies which type of structure I should load. This may be solved using unions, but the hugh difference in sizes of the structures made me decide for a structure with a void * in it:

```
struct msg {
    int type;
    void * data; /* may be any of the 50 defined structures: @see type */
};
```

The problem with that is that I need 2 `malloc` calls, and 2 `free`. For me, function calls are expensive and `malloc` is expensive. From the users side, it would be great to simple `free` the msgs. So I changed the definition to:

```
struct msg {
    int type;
    uint8_t data[]; /* flexible array member */
};
...
struct msg_10 {
    uint32_t flags[4];
    ...
};
```

Whenever I need to deserialize a message, I do:

```
struct msg * deserialize_10(uint8_t * buffer, size_t length) {
    struct msg * msg = (struct msg *) malloc(offsetof(struct msg, data) + sizeof(struct msg_10));
    struct msg_10 * payload = (__typeof__(payload))msg->data;

    /* load payload */
    return msg;
}
```

And to get a member of that structure:

```
uint32_t msg10_flags(const struct msg * msg, int i)
{
    return ((struct msg_10 *)(msg->data))->flags[i];
}
```

With this change, gcc (and g++) issue a nice `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]` message.

I think this is a common issue (but I found no answer here) on how to represent a family of messages in C, in some efficient manner.

I understand why the warning appeared, my questions are the following:

1. Is it possible to implement something like this, without the warning or is it intrinsically flawed? (the or is not exclusive :P, and I'm almost convinced I should refactor)
2. Would it be better to represent the messages using something like the following code?

   ```
   struct msg {
       int type;
   };
   ...
   struct msg_10 {
       struct msg; /* or int type; */
       uint32_t flags[4];
       ...
   };
   ```
3. If yes, caveats? Can I always write and use the following?

   ```
   struct msg * deserialize_10(uint8_t * buffer, size_t length) {
       struct msg_10 * msg = (struct msg_10 *) malloc(sizeof(struct msg_10));

       /* load payload */
       return (struct msg *)msg;
   }

   uint32_t msg10_flags(const struct msg * msg, int i) {
       const struct msg_10 * msg10 = (const struct msg_10 *) msg;
       return msg10->flags[i];
   }
   ```
4. Any other?

I forgot to say that this runs on low level systems and performance is a priority but, all in all, the real issue is how to handle this "multi-message" structure. I may refactor once, but changing the implementation of the deserialization of 50 message types...

Comment: How about `template`?

Comment: I can't, it must be C code.. but it's being compiled using g++... and I don't know why.

Comment: _"The problem with that is that I need 2 `malloc` calls, and 2 `free`."_ Why 2? Don't see any reason for 2 memory allocations here.

Comment: If it must be a C code, I think you should erase the tag C++/C++11 in your question.

Comment: @DanielLangr One for the `struct msg *` and one for the `data` field. But I'm open and looking forward for a better solution :)

Comment: @boguspato Do you need to allocate `struct msg` dynamically? If yes, consider allocating space for multiple structs at once, something as `std::vector` does.

Comment: @boguspato then you can probably only do it using your method or preprocessor/macros(which is much uglier).

Comment: The fact that your code is (incorrectly) compiled by `g++`, not by  `gcc`, should go into your question. And that fact is your real issue. Explain why. What build automation do you use?

Comment: There is no flexible array member in c++

Comment: "For me, function calls are expensive and malloc is expensive"  Sounds like you are on a system where you shouldn't be using dynamic allocation in the first place?

Comment: @Lundin I think the same but, as it's being used, I should use it after thinking about it for a while.

Comment: Did you try making the flexible data member a int64_t or int32_t rather than int8_t?

Comment: @bd2357 What is the benefit of doing that? The "flags" member is one of (possibly) many. I understand the issue is with casting the (flexible) array to a pointer to structure.

Comment: My inexperience with g++, though maybe you could trick it by moving the data portion of your structure to most general (largest) alignment. But it probable won't work since this is more related to strict casting issues. Think you #2 is best, or use GCC and call it from g++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dodge the strict aliasing, you can wrap your struct inside a union. With C11 you can use an anonymous struct to get rid of the extra level needed to access "flags":

```
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    uint32_t flags[4];
  };  
  uint8_t bytes[ sizeof(uint32_t[4]) ];
} msg_10;
```

And now you can do `msg_10* payload = (msg_10*)msg->data;` and access `payload` without worrying about strict aliasing violations, since the union type includes a type (`uint8_t[]`) compatible with the effective type of the object.

Please note however, that the pointer returned by `malloc` has no effective type until you access it through a pointer to a certain type. So alternatively, you can make sure to access the data with the correct type after malloc, and that won't give a strict aliasing violation either. Something like

```
struct msg_10 * msg = malloc(sizeof(struct msg_10));
struct msg_10 dummy = *msg;
```

Where `dummy` won't be used, it is just there to set the effective type.

Comment: Two remarks. (1) for such a solution you should probably ensure maximal alignment of the `bytes` member by means of `alignas`.  (2) A much better strategy to ensure the effective type is initialization by assignment, `*msg = (msg_10){ 0 };`, I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt Well this question got me start thinking... would it be ok to do something like `(void)*msg;` to set the effective type, or would the compiler optimize away the whole line, including the choice of effective type? I posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019295/does-giving-data-an-effective-type-count-as-a-side-effect).

Comment: no, read access only sets the type for the access, not the effective type of the object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on this. Isn't it enough to do: `msg->flags[0] = __be32_to_cpup((uint32_t*) buffer);` to set the effective type?

Comment: Neither gcc nor clang can reliably handle code which takes the address of union members and uses the resulting pointer, even in cases where the use of the pointer immediately follows the operation that takes the address.  As it happens, gcc and clang seem to correctly process code that uses the array subscripting operator on union members of array type, but from the point of view of the Standard an expression like `unionPtr->array[i]` is equivalent to ((memberType*)(unionPtr->array))[i]` since the `array` decomposes to `memberType*`, but neither gcc nor clang can recognize any association...

Comment: ...between a decomposed pointer and the underlying union, even within the same expression where the decomposition takes place.  Since almost any practical use of an array-type lvalue will require that it decompose into a pointer-to-element type, I would regard arrays within unions as being only usable in the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect of gcc and clang.

Comment: @supercat The OP mentioned no specific compiler so we'll have to assume a standard compliant one.

Comment: @Lundin: The authors of the Standard explicitly recognize in the rationale that a compiler can be conforming and yet be of such low quality as to be useless.  The way 6.5p7 is written would allow a low-quality compiler to regard almost any code as invoking UB, and allows high-quality compilers to behave usefully even when not required, so I'm not sure what "standard compliant" should be taken to mean.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm writing a C program (`g++` compilable)

This is a misunderstanding.

**C source files should be compiled by `gcc`** (*not* by `g++`). C++ source files should be compiled by `g++` (not by `gcc`). Remember that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) means [*Gnu Compiler **Collection***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (and also contains `gfortran` and `gccgo` etc... when suitably configured). So Fortran source files should be compiled with `gfortran` (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), Go source files should be compiled with `gccgo`  (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), Ada code should be compiled with `gnat` (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), and so on.

Read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Check what happens by passing also `-v` to your `gcc` or `g++` compiler command (it should invoke the `cc1` compiler, not the `cc1plus` one).

If you insist about compiling a C99 or C11 source file with `g++` (not `gcc`), which is IMHO wrong and confusing, be sure to pass at least the `-std=c99` (or `-std=gnu11` etc...) and `-x c` flags.

But you really should **fix your** [**build** automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) or build procedure to use `gcc` (not `g++`) to compile C code. Your real issue is that point (some bug in a `Makefile` or some other thing).

At link time, use `g++` if you mix C and C++ code.

Notice that [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) don't exist (and never existed) in C++, even in future C++20. In C++ you might use 0 as their declared size, e.g. code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define FLEXIBLE_DIM 0
#else
#define FLEXIBLE_DIM /*empty flexible array member*/
#endif
```

and then declare:

```
struct msg {
  int type;
  uint8_t data[FLEXIBLE_DIM]; /* flexible array member */
};
```

but this works only because `uint8_t` is a [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure), and your `g++` compiler might (sometimes) give "buffer overflow" or "index out of bounds" warnings (and you should *never* depend upon the compile-time `sizeof` of that `data` field).

Comment: Yes, it's nonsense, but it's beyond me. But you are right, and I should be careful using flexible array members.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly build something like this using makros;
`message_header` works as a parent-struct for all message-types. Being the first member of such structs they share the same address. Hence after creating `msg(int)` and casting it to a `message_header` you can free it simply by calling free on it.
(C++ works somewhat the same btw)

Is this what you wanted?

```
struct message_header {
    int type;
};

#define msg(T) struct {struct message_header header; T data} 

struct message_header* init_msg_int(int a) {
    msg(int)* result = (msg(int)*)(malloc(sizeof(msg(int))));
    result->data = a;
    return (struct message_header*)result;
}

int get_msg_int(struct message_header* msg) {
    return ((msg(int)*)msg)->data;
}

void free_msg(struct message_header* msg) {
    free(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No mallocs, no frees, no aliasing, function calls are inline**, *for simple or non-padded naturally aligned structures, inline functions are equivalent to a memcpy or register copy for small simple structures*. For more complex structures the compiler does all the heavy lifting.

Since you are deserializing, alignemnet of the byes in the buffer are likely packed and NOT naturally aligned. Take a look at the Linux Kernel source of packed_struct.h (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.8/source/include/linux/unaligned/packed_struct.h)

Instead of u16, u32, u64, roll out a function for each of your msg_0..msg_10..msg_(n-1). As you can see from the source file, it is ripe for simplifying each unaligned type and inline function with a few simple macros. Using your example names

```
struct msg {
    int type;
};
...
struct msg_10 {
    struct msg MsgStruct; /* or int type; */
    uint32_t flags[4];
    ...
};

#define UNALIGNED_STRUCT_NAME(msg_struct_tag) \
    UNA_##msg_struct_tag

#define DECLARE_UNALIGNED_STRUCT(msg_struct_tag) \
  struct UNALIGNED_STRUCT_NAME(msg_struct_tag) \
  {struct msg_struct_tag x;} __attribute__((__packed__))

#define DESERIALIZE_FN_NAME(msg_struct_tag) \
    deserialize_##msg_struct_tag

#define CALL_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_struct_tag, pbuf) \
    DESERIALIZE_FN_NAME(msg_struct_tag)(pbuf)

#define DEFINE_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_struct_tag) \
    static inline \
        struct msg_struct_tag DESERIALIZE_FN_NAME(msg_struct_tag)(const void* p) \
    { \
        const struct UNALIGNED_STRUCT_NAME(msg_struct_tag) *ptr = \
            (const struct UNALIGNED_STRUCT_NAME(msg_struct_tag) *)p; \
        return ptr->x; \
    }

...
DECLARE_UNALIGNED_STRUCT(msg_9);
DECLARE_UNALIGNED_STRUCT(msg_10);
DECLARE_UNALIGNED_STRUCT(msg_11);
...
...
DEFINE_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_9)
DEFINE_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_10)
DEFINE_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_11)
...
```

To deserialize a message 10

```
struct msg_10 ThisMsg = CALL_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_10, buffer);
```

Or to deserialize a message 13 at byte 9 in the buffer

```
struct msg_13 OtherMsg = CALL_DESERIALIZE_STRUCT_FN(msg_13, &(buffer[9]));
```